# JIRA JQL - search for issues where custom field does not exist

Tags: jira, jql

I added a new custom field "Deferred to Date". Because custom fields are optional, none of the existing issues have it.

Now I want a JQL search query for all issues where the deferred date is null (doable) or the deferred date field doesn't exist for the record (this is what I can't find).

I looked at the JQL instructions at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching but I don't see anything for checking whether or not a field exists.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Try searching for "MyFieldName is empty"

Comment: I tried that. No luck. Do you know it to work? I don't think it does what you think it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JQL query that you need is

```
"Deferred to Date" is empty
```

Or (equivalent),

```
"Deferred to Date" is null
```

However, if you have just added the new custom field, then you need to re-index your JIRA instance before either of these JQL queries will work.

The "Re-Index" button can be found in the JIRA Admin under "Indexing",

- JIRA Admin
- General Configuration
- Indexing
- Re-Index

Comment: Re-indexing was the key for me. Couple hours lost on this

Answer (score 2):

Like Andrew mentioned, in order to get "**is EMPTY**" to work after a custom field is added, you will have to re-index Jira.

This may not always be feasible in production environment, especially if new custom fields are being created frequently (which is most likely the case if you use a plugin like [CM4J](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213372/cm4j-context-manager-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview), allowing project admins to configure multi-context custom fields).

Fortunately, if you have [Scriptrunner for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) installed, you can use the following JQL query to get all instances of a specific empty field without re-indexing:

```sql
issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("<sub-query>", "<field name>", "^$")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reindex your jira instance, may be that the problem

Comment: Please expand on your answer (ie. what will a re-index do)